# Passing (object.function) as a parameter

Tags: javascript, methods, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm building a simple drag and drop uploader using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) however I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` when I try and pass a method (object.function) as the parameter for the promise's callback functions resolve/reject.

I'm looking to organize my promise callbacks as methods underneath the `resolve` and `reject` objects so in the case of upload it would be `resolve.upload` and `reject.upload`, and for example if I had a signin promise for say user authentication then it would be ie. `resolve.signin` and `reject.signin`.

The current promise pattern is to chain then(), catch(), reject(), resolve() this is a horrible programming pattern if your using sockets and chain 2+ async calls the code becomes hard to manage as you nest more and more anonymous functions also known as the [pyramid of doom pattern](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-callback-hell-promises-generators/), to avoid this pattern, I'm using another one that I've used countless times for async calls as I'm doing in the below code when I set async event listeners `client.addEventListener(prop, callback.upload[prop]);` and handle them in a separate object `callback.upload.event`.

In the same way I'm handling the callback response for async request, I am trying to implement for promises to avoid chaining/nesting 5-10 async request in so long unmanageable function, however passing a methods (object.function) for callback functions for the promises `function(resolve.upload,reject.upload)` doesn't seem to work, however is I pass a global function (function) ie, `resolve` or `reject` it will work just fine, however this is not good since it will be cluttering up the global namespace and is why I'm trying to pass a `object.method`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/upload.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script>
        //EVENT LISTENERS
        var listen = {
            drag: ['dragenter','dragover','drop','dragleave'],
            async: ['readystatechange','loadstart','progress','abort','error','load','timeout','loadend']
        };
        //PROMISES
       var executor = {
            //THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM LIES
            upload: function(resolve.upload,reject.upload){
                var data = new FormData();
                var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
                data.append('xls', executor.upload.files); 
                for(prop of listen.async){ 
                    client.addEventListener(prop, callback.upload[prop]);
                }
                client.open("POST", "/core/upload.php");
                client.send(data);
            }
        };
        //PROMISES HANDLERS
        var resolve = {
            upload: function(value){
                 console.log(value);
            }
        };
        var reject = {
             upload: function(reason){
                 console.log(reason);
             }
        };
        //USER HANDLERS
        var handles = {
            upload: {
                dragenter: function(e){
                    e.target.classList.remove('emboss');
                }
                dragover: function(e){
                     e.preventDefault();
                }
                drop: function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    executor.upload.files = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
                    //CREATE PROMISE
                    var p = new Promise(executor.upload);
                    console.log(p);
                    //CHECK PROMISE STATUS, EVERY 3 SECS
                    setInterval(function(){
                        console.log(p);
                    }, 3000);
                }
                dragleave: function(e){
                     e.target.classList.add('emboss');
                }
            }
        };

        //ASYNC HANDLERS
        var callback = {
            upload: {
                readystatechange: function(e){
                    console.log(e.target.readyState);
                }
                loadstart: function(e){ 
                    console.log('loadstart');
                }
                progress: function(e){
                    console.log('progress');
                }
                abort: function(e){
                    console.log('abort');
                }
                error: function(e){
                    console.log('error');
                }
                load: function(e){
                    console.log('load');
                }
                timeout: function(e){
                    console.log('timeout');
                }
                loadend: function(e){
                    console.log('loadend');
                }
            }   
        };

        //INITIALIZATION
        function init(){
            var dropbox = document.getElementById('dropbox');
            for(prop of listen.drag){ 
                dropbox.addEventListener(prop, handles.upload[prop]);}
            };
        //CALL INIT
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dropbox" class="fa fa-file-excel-o fa-4x emboss"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you need to define the callbacks before the executor object?

Comment: @IrkenInvader yea thats the first thing I thought but I changed it and still the same error

Comment: This is bizarre in so many respects, it's hard to know where to start.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 it's really not bizarre at all, I'm simply trying to find a way to organize the callbacks inside an object. You can easily do it with async callbacks like I am in the code above under the callback object, by setting a event listener on the load `events(client, prop, callback.upload[prop])` event of the async call. I'll be putting a bounty on this question.

Comment: I can't make any sense whatsoever of what you're trying to achieve here, and I'm very familiar with Promises.  Please step back from your proposed solution, and describe what it is that you're trying to achieve, and expose to the user.

Comment: "*Why can't I pass the object functions as parameters*" - because you can pass them as arguments only, when you *call* the function. Where you are getting the syntax error, you're *declaring* parameter names, which must not use dots but be identifiers.

Comment: @Alnitak every promise comes with the callbacks.... what I'm trying to do is simply organize those callbacks under the `resolve` and `reject` objects as methods just like I am doing with the async listeners underneath the `callback` object i.e `callback.upload.whateverevent` I'm trying to organize the callbacks for promises `resolve.upload`.

Comment: no, promises _don't_ "come with" callbacks - Promises are passed a function (when they're constructed) that will then be invoked with two parameters, the `resolve` and `reject` functions, which are themselves callbacks back _into_ the Promise object.

Comment: @Alnitak yes yes call it what you want I know what you mean, my point is I'm trying to pass a function which is an object method and it won't let me. I want my promise 'callbacks' to be `resolve.upload` and `reject.upload`.

Comment: and we're saying you can't do that - the `resolve` and `reject` parameters _belong to the Promise object and are created by it_ - you can't "pass" them.    Please, go up at least one level of abstraction and explain the whole problem, ideally without cluttering with the rest of the async stuff.

Comment: @Bergi yea exactly if I don't use `.` or `[]`, basically if I don't use object functions (methods) ie. `reject`, `resolve` rather than `reject.upload` and `resolve.upload` then it will work fine but then my global namespace is going to be taken up.

Comment: @JordanDavis: Nope, this has nothing to do with the global namespace. You're declaring parameter names here, which are *local variables* in your function.

Comment: @Bergi yes that is the current promise pattern and I  do understand that but if your chaining 5 to 6 together its simply a horrible way to organize and program. It will work fine if you pass in functions that aren't local variables however it's not working when I pass a method (object.function) if you change them to `resolve = (value)=> console.log(value)` and `reject = (reason)=> console.log(reason)` they are outside of the function (not local) and work just fine.

Comment: @JordanDavis please explain what you code is _actually supposed to do_.  I've looked at the Fiddle, and I still can't tell, because nowhere that I can see do you actually create a valid Promise object, or use the methods that are exposed by one.

Comment: @JordanDavis: I think you actually have some greater scoping problems than worrying about parameter names.

Comment: @Alnitak `var p = new Promise(executor.upload)`

Comment: @JordanDavis right, so you're passing a function, that's actually OK.  However the declared parameters to that function - ` (resolve.upload,reject.upload)` - are not.  Those are _parameters_, whose values are set _by the Promise constructor_, and cannot simply be replaced with values of your own choosing.

Comment: @Bergi I really don't... look at this line in the code above to handle the callback on the async `for(prop of listen.async){ events(client, prop, callback.upload[prop]);}` I'm setting the response handler aka `load` and I'm logging in via `callback.upload.load` method

Comment: @Alnitak agreed yea were getting close, but they actually can be as long as they aren't methods... so if they are global functions it works, but this will fill up your namespaces when you add other promises... think of it this way the current pattern for promises is to keep nesting and chaining .then().catch().resolve().reject() etc.... which is ridiculous, its the same pattern as if you were to chain 5-10 anonymous functions together it's simply bad programming... being able to organize all promise rejects and responses in a object which would just contain the associated method.

Comment: Promises enable some very clean programming.  OTOH I'm having a hell of a job making sense of your code.  Go figure... :p

Comment: @Alnitak look at the code for the `callback.upload` all the event listeners are organized right there for that 'upload' async call.... now if I wanted to do another async call lets say user signin i would just do `callback.signin` and handle all the events for that under there.

Comment: @Alnitak yes if you have like 1-2 interactions... not at all if your using sockets and or 5-10 interactions, just think if you were to handle an async response and then just keep chaining more like 5-10 using if/then instead of resolve/reject basically what promises are lol. and yea prbly the fat arrow syntax lol I can change if you would like?

Comment: change if you like, but I've _still_ no idea overall what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Alnitak I changed it, and simply trying to handle the resolve and reject callbacks outside of the function, specifically inside an object as a object.method `resolve.upload`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass your own callbacks to the function passed to the Promise constructor.  What you can do is register callbacks in the subsequent chain, e.g.:

```
var p = new Promise(executor.upload).then(resolve.upload, reject.upload);
```

However for this to be useful the `execute.upload` function must actually invoke the passed `resolve` and `reject` parameters based on what the `XMLHttpRequest` object does:

```
executor.upload = (resolve, reject) => {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

    client.addEventListener('readystatechange', (e) => {
        // call `resolve` or `reject` as appropriate
    });

    // then register any more specific handlers
    for (prop of listen.async){ 
        client.addEventListener(prop, callback.upload[prop]);
    }

    client.open("POST", "/core/upload.php");
    client.send(data);
}
```

It's the action of calling `resolve()` or `reject()` *inside the Promise constructor's callback* that ultimately results in the handlers registered with `.then` being called.

Comment: hmmm let me try that out.

Comment: do note that adding these promises to your code doesn't enable any functionality that isn't already possible using your existing `readystatechange` hook.

Comment: I tried something like this before, but this definitely a step forward and really close! I understand that you have to call resolve/reject inside but there is got to be a way to to call it from the `callback.upload.events` object... so basically if the async call errors then the `callback.upload.error` method fires and we can call then call `reject()` and if no errors then `callback.upload.load` will fire and `resolve()` you know what I mean.

Comment: @JordanDavis ok, but ask yourself what you're trying to achieve by adding Promises into the mix.  Promises are supposed to _avoid_ the callback pyramid of doom, and are a good way of abstracting async methods, but it's not clear what additional benefit they add here.

Comment: agreed and thats kind of what my point is by asking this, so that event listener object callback pattern I design awhile ago to fix the pyramid of doom and it does, but when I saw the ES6 spec adopting promises I mean yea they somewhat fix the pyramid of doom but really they don't because if you have 2+ and any logic within those its still a mess and unorganized pattern, don't get me wrong its a step up but still wouldn't you agree that looping through setting the callbacks and handling the callbacks in a separate object would be the most fluid way between the two?

Comment: I mean if you make a async request and it fails you already have a "reject()" and if it succeeds you have a "resovle()" ie (error|load) so why the hell did they even make promises you know? makes no sense to me in this aspect, and seems very useless to adopt in my code.

Comment: In essence the answer to your code problem is "don't use Promises, then!"  :)  However Promises _are_ an exceedingly useful way of abstracting asynchronous code into a common API and often result in very simple to follow code (and almost always simpler than a pyramid of callbacks).   I *like* that I can make HTTP calls, do database lookups, wait for timers, jQuery animations, etc, all within a `Promise` based framework.

Comment: I mean the pattern I'm using is the furthest thing from the pyramid of doom, because I'm not handling the callbacks locally I'm handling them with a external object.method and I can access the server response by passing the `(e)`-event and `e.target.response` inside the external method . This object method pattern to me seems way more organized then both doom and promises. I would assume most ppl don't code from scratch and rely on some type of framework ie. jQuery which locks them into using that specific async pattern which then I can see Promises would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time by the way :)

Answer (score 1):

In the "fatarrow" syntax:

```
(param1, param2) => { thing to be returned }
```

the names in the parens on the left side are the names local to the `{ thing to be returned }` part.  In fact, other than a difference in "this", about all fatarrow amounts to is a syntactical shorthand.  So these two function definitions are basically identical:

```
blah: ( alpha, bravo ) => alpha + ", " + bravo
function blah ( alpha, bravo ) { return alpha + ", " + bravo; }
```

You want:

```
upload: ( resfunc, rejfunc ) => { ...etc... }
```

and wherever you CALL upload is where you would go:

```
upload(resolve.upload, reject.upload)
```

I'm also not sure about your use of promises.  It is my understanding that the callbacks are given to you for you to call.  That is, something like this.

```
var promise = new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
        img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 300, 100);
            resolve();                          // done, tell the promise
        };
        img.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCwALAIAAAAAA3pn/ZiH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAALAAsAAAIUhA+hkcuO4lmNVindo7qyrIXiGBYAOw==';
    }
);
```

Then you can use something like:

```
promise.then ( function () { /* promise says it is done, do something */ } );
```

Comment: so your saying call `(resolve,reject) => { things to be returned }` then in my async handlers ie `callback.upload.load` in my example, call to `resolve.upload('my success msg')`

Comment: I understand what your saying but what I'm trying to do is organize my callbacks as methods ie `callback.upload.load`.  rather then the inline `.onload` anonymous functions, there has to be a way to do it... as well as the same pattern to handle the resolve and reject callbacks...

Comment: If I am understanding this, I think what you want is that `executor.upload` returns a function.  Something like `var f = function(resolve, reject) { /* ...do whatever you need this function to do, calling resolve and reject as appropriate */ }; return f;`

Comment: right but instead of setting the async listeners inline using `.onload` you do it the 'correct' way using the DOM3 `addEventListener` method. So if you look at my example code I attach all the async listener and handle the response via `callback.upload.whatever-event-that-fires` in this case we really only care about the `onload` aka `callback.upload.load`. I'll update my code in the example for more clarity.

Comment: Your two functions are *not* identical. Arrow functions have lexical `this`, whereas "regular" functions can get `this` bound to any object.

Comment: Yes, I glossed over that.  Thanks.

Comment: "It is my understanding that the callbacks are given to you for you to call" - Yes exactly so. A Promise's executor function is said to "reveal" the Promise's `resolve` and `reject` methods. These methods are made available by this mechanism alone.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have `{ thing to be returned }` then on the next line `{ return me }`?  They look like they should be the same.  Also, you have "parens on the left size", but it should be si**d**e instead of si**z**e.